# Why are the .selectAll() D3-created circles in my SVG said to be 1 element using .length?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I suspect that the answer lies somewhere between my ignorance of what kind of object I'm actually working and the inner darkness of D3 and/or SVG.

I can see 30 circles on the screen. So I go in the console like this.

```
var circles  = d3.select("#svg1").selectAll("circle");  
>undefined  

circles;  
>[Array[30]]...  

circles.length;  
>1
```

I know I'm targeting the right elements because executing *.remove()* on the set clears them from the screen. But what's up with the count?

Comment: Because, the `circles` is an array that contains a single element which itself is an array containing 30 elements. Use `circles[0].length`

Comment: @Tushar Right. Got it. As I asked Fawzan - is it always like this in D3-context? Or do we ever have an array with multiple arrays?

Comment: You get multiple top-level elements e.g. for nested selections. This is well documented -- see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections section "Operating on selections".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var circles = d3.select("#svg1").selectAll("circle");
```

`circles` is an array of array, hence the length is `1`. That is the length of the outer array. If you want to get the count of circles selected then you should use `d3`s built-in method `size`.

```
var count = d3.select("#svg1").selectAll("circle").size();
```

This will give you the expected result.

Comment: Is there ever more than one array in the outer array (in the context of D3, data and such)? If so, will the *size()* statement give the sum of all components in all inner arrays?

Comment: according to the mikes documentation select() returns an array of elements pulled from the current document. size() returns the number of elements selected.

Comment: So, to verify - there's always only one inner array in the outer array? And regarding the size - I'm not sure if it was a yes, a no or something else...  :)

Comment: My Bad. Sorry. size() will not give the size of innerArray. If you use a select query `d3.select('blahblah')` it will give an array(array(1)). inner array will have `null` in index `0`. so the length of the inner array is `1` but the size will surely return `0` for the selector.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I interpreted your answer, so you got it right. Length is the number of elements in the array. Size is the number of elements in the subelements calculated recursively. Makes sense.