# Existing elements in D3 SVG chart aren't updated - all is regarded as exit() and enter() sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg, data-binding

I'm playing around with a graph charting 13 g-elements with a circle each. Then I execute the following in the console. Verification gives me that *copy* contains 13 elements, *shorty* 7 and *longy* 20. Nothing on the screen changes, just yet, of course.

```
var gees = d3.select("#graph2").selectAll("g");
var copy = gees.data();
var shorty = copy.slice(0,7)
var longy = shorty.concat(copy);
```

Now, that I execute the following, I expected a difference in the data set but not the way I see. If we start off with 13 elements and subtract 6 (as is the case with *shorty*), the *enter()* set should be 0 and the *exit()* set should be 6, the way I figure. However, my console proudly shows that it's 7 and 13. Equivalently, if we start off with 13 elements and add 7 (as is the case with *longy*), the *enter()* set should be 7 and the *exit()* set should be 0, as far I can understand. Yet again, my console surprises me claiming that it's 20 and 13.

```
gees.data(shorty).enter()
gees.data(shorty).exit()
```

> [Array[7]]
>   [Array[13]]

```
gees.data(longy).enter()
gees.data(longy).exit()
```

> [Array[20]]
>   [Array[13]]

The conclusion I'm drawing is that **all** the pre-exisint elements are discarded (hence put in the *exit()* set) and the added data is regarded as a brand new bunch (hence regarded as *enter()* set). I can live with that but all the articles I've read stated that **every and each** operation on sets should be relying on:

1. updating stuff in *data()*
2. appending stuff in *enter()*
3. removing stuff in *exit()*

Comment: @Fawzan The question is *why do I get set sizes of 7 and 13 when the expected set sizes are 0 and 6?* (for the first change to a smaller set). Equivalently for the other case. It seems to me that there's never anything in the non-enter and non-exit set.

Comment: @Fawzan He confused the arrays. I've stumbled upon [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35101354/1675891) from yesterday. That's why I got the answer so quickly so you got +1 there as a credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sets are of correct sizes. You're just not looking at the **sizes**. You got tricked by the data presentation of your console. Running these commands should clear the confusion. I've done that on circles not gs but it the same logic.

```js
mySet.data(shorterSet).exit().size()
```

> 6

```
mySet.data(shorterSet).enter().size()
```

> 0

```
mySet.data(longerSet).exit().size()
```

> 0

```
mySet.data(longerSet).enter().size()
```

> 7